# Did the Sardaukar used to be prisoners?

Tags: dune

It's rather a long time since I've read the Dune books and when listening to the Sardaukar Chant, I remembered something of the Sardaukar being from a prison planet and started to check their origin.

> The abilities of the Sardaukar were largely attributed to the harsh environment and brutal discipline they were exposed to on planet Salusa Secundus, the Corrino prison planet.
>
> From the Dune.Fandom [article on Sardaukar](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Sardaukar)

The [article on Salusa Secundus](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Salusa_Secundus#Prison_planet) from the same site does not detail this further:

> Due to the harshness of Salusa Secundus, it became the Corrino prison planet. Those who broke imperial law and were judged guilty were sentenced to be imprisoned on the planet. Many in the empire suspected that the harshness of this world was responsible for breeding Sardaukar troops.

The French Wikipedia [article on the Sardaukar](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardaukar) states:

> Les Sardaukars sont sélectionnés au sein de la population carcérale de la planète-prison Salusa Secundus

Translated: The Sardaukars are selected from the prison population of the prison planet Salusa Secundus.

I did not find any other sources confirming this interpretation and the author of the article does not cite a clear source (or if it's his understanding). However, the English Wikipedia [article on Organizations in the Dune universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizations_of_the_Dune_universe#Sardaukar) states:

> They are secretly trained on the inhospitable Imperial prison planet Salusa Secundus, and the harsh conditions there ensure that only the strongest and most "ferocious" men survive.

So, were the Sardaukar raised from the prisoners of the planet (or maybe their offspring) or was it a different part of the planet (the prison being e.g. a continent and the Sardaukar inhabitants of another continent)? Or were they only trained there but had their origins from another planet?

I am aware that prison planet implies the whole planet is a prison but it could (IMO) also be that only a big part of the planet was for the prison or that the Emperor used this as a distraction for the other Noble Houses not to find the source of his Sardaukar Warriors, denying access to it "to ensure that prisoners do not flee".

Comment: Dune has Hawat and the Baron speculating about the origin of the Sardaukar; "*How could you be sure of the loyalty of such recruits?” “I would take them in small groups, not larger than platoon strength,” Hawat said. “I’d remove them from their oppressive situation and isolate them with a training cadre of people who understood their background, preferably people who had preceded them from the same oppressive situation. Then I’d fill them with the mystique that their planet had really been a secret training ground to produce just such superior beings as themselves"*

Comment: I’m not going to suggest they’re prisoners, but “Swing Low” happens to be the Sardaukar’s favorite song.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks, I partly remembered something like that but wasn't able to find it in the books/online.

Comment: Would you accept answers that are based from the Dune Encyclopedia?

Comment: @fez - Post it and let the community decide. Personally I like the encyclopaedia as a source. It's not as good as the original books but a darn sight better than the games and recent novels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My 1977 edition of Dune contains a glossary or 'Terminology of the Imperium' Here's the entry for Salusa Secundus:

> SALUSA SECUNDUS: third planet of Gamma Waiping: designated Imperial Prison Planet after removal of the Royal Court to Kaitan. Salusa Secundus is homeworld of House Corrino, and the second stopping Point in migrations of the Wondering Zensunni. Fremen tradition says they were slaves on S.S. for nine generations.

and for Sarduakar:

> SARDAUKAR: the soldier-fanatics if the Padishah Emperor. They were men from an environmental background of such ferocity that it killed six out of every thirteen persons before the age of eleven. Their military training emphasized ruthlessness and a near-suicidal disregard for personal safety.

The way I read this, the entire planet being a prison implies the population cannot leave and no-one can enter. Combined with the fact the Fremen were imprisoned there for multiple generations implies it is the entire population that are held prisoner on a single world. A world with such brutal conditions that only the strongest survive and are selected for the Sardaukar. It isn't a prison in the sense that if you steal a loaf of bread on Arrakis, you get sent to Salusa Secundus but rather that the population of that world are held captive to produce soldiers for House Corrino.